# Empty data points in DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, dem

I have a Himalayan DEM with missing data. You can see empty white dots that later affect me when generating .stl files. How can I "color" these empty spots with the nearby spots? They should be the same or similar height as nearby data points.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the GDAL "Fill nodata" utility under Raster --> Analysis.

Documentation on the tool can be read [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasteranalysis.html#fill-nodata).

Comment: Solved! Thank you @archimedes!